# How do I filter my database query to not include records based on an associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model where users rate other users. They do that through a many-to-many association with a table called ratings that has rater_id and ratee_id fields that correspond to user_id (a many-to-many self join on User). The models are:

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_many :ratings_as_rater, class_name: "Rating", foreign_key: "rater_id"
has_many :ratings_as_ratee, class_name: "Rating", foreign_key: "ratee_id"

# app/models/rating.rb
belongs_to :rater, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :ratee, class_name: "User"
```

And there is a compound index on the ratings table:

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "rater_id"
  t.integer "ratee_id"
  t.integer "rate" # Users rated on scale 1-4
  t.index ["ratee_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_ratee_id"
  t.index ["rater_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_rater_id"
  t.index ["rater_id", "ratee_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_rater_id_and_ratee_id", unique: true
end
```

On the user index page I only want to display the users that the current_user has not yet rated. So in the users_controller instead of:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

How would I only display users that the current_user has not yet rated? Current_user id is stored in the session cookie.

Comment: you have `current_user` method define right?

Comment: then just type this `current_user.ratings_as_ratee`

Comment: uzaif - Current_user is defined. But if I put @users = current_user.ratings_as_ratee in the User controller's index action it seems to be creating Rating objects instead of User objects.

Comment: uzaif - You put me on the right path and I found the solution. Thanks. I added another association in the User model: has_many :rated_users, through: :ratings_as_rater, source: :ratee. Then my user_controller index action changes to: @users = current_user.rated_users

Comment: awesome man. happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup a an indirect association its pretty straight forward:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings_as_rater, class_name: "Rating", foreign_key: "rater_id"
  has_many :ratings_as_ratee, class_name: "Rating", foreign_key: "ratee_id"
  has_many :raters, through: :ratings_as_ratee,
                    source: :rater
  has_many :rated_users, through: :ratings_as_rater,
                    source: :ratee

  # class level scope to fetch users with no rating
  def self.unrated_users
    left_outer_joins(:ratings_as_rater).where(ratings: { id: nil })
  end

  # users not rated by this user
  def unrated_users
    self.class.where.not(id: self.rated_users)
  end
end
```

One important performance aspect is doing `User.where.not(id: self.rated_users)` and not `User.where.not(id: self.rated_users.ids)`. This lets ActiveRecord construct a subselect instead of pulling out the ids from the DB into Ruby and then putting them back into a mega long query.

Comment: Thanks, I had come up with this already but I used the less optimal way of plucking the ids like you said. Looking at both ways I see what you mean.